# Does the Detect Method from Smalltalk Exist in Java?

Tags: java, smalltalk, java-8

I was searching for the method `detect` in Java 8. I used to use it in Smalltalk, but Java seems not to have it. Smalltalk's `detect` method finds the first element depending on the result from an expression. For example:

```
Listnumbers.detect[number->number>4]
```

If an element bigger than 4 exists, then it returns that element.

Comment: What do you want to detect?

Comment: depends of what you mean by "detect"... could you be more specific, maybe an example would help

Comment: detect: aBlock returns the first element of the collection for which aBlock evaluates to true. (from http://www.ipass.net/vmalik/smalltalk.html#Q16)

Comment: Please update your question with a description of what detect does

Answer (score 9):

In java 8 you can use the stream API:

```
Collection<T> collection = ... //

Optional<T> optionalFirst = collection.stream()
                              .filter(e -> /* some predicate */)
                              .findFirst();
```

That will find the first element in the collection that satisfies the predicate if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Or without streams you can do

```
for(T t: collection)
   if(t.test()) {
       // do something with t
       break;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) which was inspired by Smalltalk, you will find the methods `detect:` and `detect:ifNone:` that can be used with Java 8 lambdas.

For example:

```
MutableList<Integer> numbers = Lists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Integer result = numbers.detect(each -> each > 4);
Assert.assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(5), result);
```

There are more examples of using `detect`, `select`, `reject`, `collect` with Eclipse Collections and Java 8 in [this article on InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/articles/GS-Collections-by-Example-2).  Eclipse Collections 7.x can also be used with applications that are still running on Java 5 - 7.

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.